# Site collection using incorrect database

Tags: 2010

I think I have found a very bad issue with our SharePoint portal that could cause stability issues.
The WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams should have been used only with the project teams site collection. Instead it appears that I have multiple site collections duplicating to this database.

Our site collection databases are as follows:

**/                              - WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams**

/costcenters/adminServicesOps  - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_AdminServiceOps

/costcenters/assemblyAdmin - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_AssemblyAdmin

/costcenters/assemblyControls - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_AssemblyControls

/costcenters/assemblyMechanical  - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_AssemblyMech

**/costcenters/BackUpRestore  - WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams**

/costcenters/businessDev - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_BusinessDev

/costcenters/cis - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_CIS

/costcenters/engServices - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_EngServices

**/costcenters/Environmental  - WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams**

/costcenters/exec - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_Executive

/costcenters/finance - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_Finance

/costcenters/hr - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_HR

/costcenters/logistics - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_Logistics

/costcenters/pmo - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_PMO

/costcenters/SearchCenter  - WSS_Content_TKSEportal

/costcenters/service - WSS_Content_Collab_CC_Service

**/costcenters/projectteams - WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams**

/projects/Home - WSS_Content_TKSEportal

Because the main directory is using WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams; BackUpRestore & Environmental were also added to it. If I am not mistaken this means that information is being replicated in the WSS_Content_Collab_ProjectTeams datebase. As a result, this one database alone is 30269.81 MB with only 983.16 MB of available space.
To give you an example of where the projectteam database should be; I checked the WSS_Content_Collab_CC_CIS and its currently sitting at 985.44 MB.
I posted a question about this in stack overflow but apparently I did not make myself clear and they closed the thread because they thought this was a server issue.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content databases were not set to offline, when new site collections are created through Central Admin, it will randomly pick an available content database to put the new site collection in.

Simply set the undesired content databases to offline and use Powershell to move the sites to the desired datbase:

```
Move-SPSite <http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName> -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
```

Then no new created site collections will end up in the wrong content databases if provisioned through central administration.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125874.aspx

Comment: That looks like it just might work. I am working on a backup right now. I will try that tonight. Thanks